# Getting Data from text file into array and plotting it in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to read Data from a text file and then plot it usint PHPplot.
Text file looks like this:

```
0   24
1   28
2   30
3   35
4   40
```

I am trying to convert the data into something like:

```
array(array(0,24),array(1,28),array(2,30),array(3,35),array(4,40))
```

my code in php is like this

```
 $file = fopen("data2.txt", "r");;
            while (!feof($file)) {
                $line_of_text .= fgets($file);
            }
            $members = explode("\n", $line_of_text);
            fclose($file);

for ($j=0; $j<=10; $j++)
  {       
  $parts[$j]=explode("   ", $members[$j]);       
  }
# plot 
require_once 'phplot.php';
    for ($x = 0; $x <= 5; $x += 1)
      $data[] = array('', $parts[$x][0], $parts[$x][1]);
    $plot = new PHPlot(800, 600);
    $plot->SetPrintImage(False); // No automatic output
    $plot->SetImageBorderType('plain');
    $plot->SetPlotType('lines');
    $plot->SetDataType('data-data');
    $plot->SetDataValues($data);
    $plot->SetPlotAreaWorld(0, 0, 10, 40);
    $plot->SetDrawYGrid(True);
    $plot->DrawGraph();
```

the problem is in line:

```
$data[] = array('', $parts[$x][0], $parts[$x][1]);
```

that it does not draw the  $parts[$x][1] numbers. when I say print $parts[$x][1] values it prints it on the browser but just do not plot it. the interesting part is that when I ask it to plot

```
$data[] = array('', $parts[$x][0], $parts[$x][1]);
```

It Plots this time!!

var_dump($parts) gave:

```
array(11) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "0" [1]=> string(3) "24 " } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(3) "28 " } [2]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(3) "30 " } [3]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "3" [1]=> string(3) "35 " } [4]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "4" [1]=> string(2) "40" } [5]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } [6]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } [7]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } [8]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } [9]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } [10]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } }
```

also var_dump($data) gave:

```
array(5) { [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> int(0) [2]=> string(3) "24 " } [1]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> int(1) [2]=> string(3) "28 " } [2]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> int(2) [2]=> string(3) "30 " } [3]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> int(3) [2]=> string(3) "35 " } [4]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> int(4) [2]=> string(2) "40" } }
```

please help me thanks alot

Comment: what you get if var_dump($data) ?

Comment: I did var_dump($parts) got this:  array(11) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "0" [1]=> string(3) "24 " } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(3) "28 " } [2]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(3) "30 " } [3]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "3" [1]=> string(3) "35 " } [4]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "4" [1]=> string(2) "40" } [5]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } [6]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } [7]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } [8]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } [9]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } [10]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } }

Comment: please paste in your question

Comment: I pasted it in my question thanks

Comment: @GBD I pasted it in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reza, per your vardump, the values in your array are strings and the array you showed in your question had ints. Here is one way to convert these strings to ints.

```
    for ($j=0; $j<=10; $j++){
        $tmp=explode("   ", $members[$j]);
        for($k=0; $k<count($tmp); $k++){
            $tmp[$k] = intval($tmp[$k]);
        }
        $parts[$j]=$tmp;     
    }
```

Comment: not a problem, please confirm solution if this worked for you.